# Echo data json by json_decode

Tags: php, json

I want echo value json_encode by json_decode, how is it?

Following php code is my try that not work:

```
$json = '[{"dg_j":"1390\/02\/05","dg_sh":"2011\/4\/25"}]';

$obj = json_decode($json);

echo $obj->{'dg_j'};
echo '<br>';
echo $obj->{'dg_sh'};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you've got is actually an array that contains a single object. You'd want

```
$obj[0]->dg_j
```

Doing a `var_dump($obj)` will show you what the JSON actually turned into.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either **var_dump()** or **print_r()**. var_dump is preferable as it would print all levels of object hierarchy.