# How do I parse a JSON object in PHP?

Tags: php, json, parsing, post

I've got a JSON object that I'm sending to a PHP script and I'm having trouble parsing the JSON. Here's the POST request:

```
http://mywebsite.com?action=somefunction&{%22id%22:1,%22Name%22:%22Mike%22}
```

And here's my PHP function, which obviously doesn't work:

```
$data = $_GET['data'];
$obj = json_decode($data);
echo $obj->Name;
die();
```

The end goal is to extract the name "Mike" from the URL string. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do a var_dump on $obj.

Comment: Your query string is wrong.. there is no `data=`.

Comment: You're right. What should this be instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try taking a look at what PHP is outputting from `json_decode()`:

```
$data = $_GET['data'];
$obj = json_decode($data);
var_dump($obj);
```

Your code itself works fine: http://ideone.com/0jsjgT

But your query string is missing the `data=` before the actual JSON. This:

```
http://mywebsite.com?action=somefunction&{%22id%22:1,%22Name%22:%22Mike%22}
```

should be this:

```
http://mywebsite.com?action=somefunction&data={%22id%22:1,%22Name%22:%22Mike%22}
```

Comment: Ahh, you're right! But even with data set in the URL, why doesn't this work? $data = $_GET['data']; $obj = json_decode($data);

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Turned out I needed stripslashes($data), then it worked!

Answer (score 1):

you should do

```
echo $obj->{'Name'};
```

This also is a duplicate question of [Echo data json by json_decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823563/echo-data-json-by-json-decode)

Comment: What is the difference to call it without `{}` ??

Comment: `$obj->Name` and `$obj->{'Name'}` are equivalent in this case; this answer is useless.

Comment: @hek2mgl there is none  (in this case) :P