# Volley JsonArrayRequest Post request is not working

Tags: android, android-volley

I am new to Volley and i'm trying to make Post request work with

> JsonArrayRequest

From many answers I've found on stackoverflow, I tried as follows -

```
    private void getCounts() {
    String url = "http://192.168.1.100/json/count.php";
    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidepDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            hidepDialog();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("LastUpdatedAt", "0");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            headers.put("User-agent", "My useragent");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("LastUpdatedAt", "0");

            if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, encodeParameters(params, getParamsEncoding()).toString());
                return encodeParameters(params, getParamsEncoding());
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected byte[] encodeParameters(Map<String, String> params, String paramsEncoding) {
            StringBuilder encodedParams = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                    encodedParams.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), paramsEncoding));
                    encodedParams.append('=');
                    encodedParams.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), paramsEncoding));
                    encodedParams.append('&');
                }
                return encodedParams.toString().getBytes(paramsEncoding);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + paramsEncoding, uee);
            }
        }

    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

**As one can see, I have tried both, `getParams()` and `getBody()` to send `LastUpdatedAt` as Post request, but no matter what I try the value is not posted and returns null on server.**

I even tried with using `JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, ...` and also by sending 'params' as JsonObject in the request, but even these two didn't work.

In one of the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048806/volley-sending-a-post-request-using-jsonarrayrequest), use of following class is suggested -

```
public class CustomJsonRequest extends Request {

Map<String, String> params;       
private Response.Listener listener; 

public CustomJsonRequest(int requestMethod, String url, Map<String, String> params,
                      Response.Listener responseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

    super(requestMethod, url, errorListener);
    this.params = params;
    this.listener = responseListener;
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(Object response) {
    listener.onResponse(response); 

}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
         return params;
}

@Override
protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
        HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}

}
```

But I couldn't make working Response listner `createRequestSuccessListener` and its error listener.

In the same similar question, following constructor is suggested -

```
public JsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
        Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), 
        listener, errorListener);
}
```

But, I could not figure out how to make it work?

Comment: I couldn't understand where *exactly* your problem is. However, I also had several issues making POST requests using volley in the past. This answer solved my problem, maybe you could look at it and see whether it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837820/volley-jsonobjectrequest-post-request-not-working/19945676#19945676

Answer (score 2):

Try to do something like:

```
        String url = "http://192.168.1.100/json/count.php";

        final JSONObject _jsonRequest = new JSONObject();
        _jsonRequest.put("key", value);

        JsonArrayRequest _stringRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
         url , new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                // Your code here

            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                // Your code here

            }

        }){

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() {

                try {

                    return _jsonRequest.toString().getBytes(getParamsEncoding());

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {

                    return null;

                }

            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> _params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                _params.put("Content-type", "application/json");

                return _params;

            }

        };

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(_stringRequest);
```

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. There is some conflict with `JsonArrayRequest` and `Response.Listener<String>`. So, if I try to put your code as such, it shows error. If I replace `String` with `JSONArray` at both places, it runs. but then throws error - `com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value You of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. You should change `Response.Listener<String>` to `Response.Listener<JSONArray>`. Now the showed message error is because of what the server send back. It must be sending a `String` instead of `Array`. So in this case you have to use `StringRequest` instead of `JsonArrayRequest` and change `Response.Listener<JSONArray>` to `Response.Listener<String>` as well as `public void onResponse(JSONArray response)` to `public void onResponse(String response)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I mentioned in my earlier comment, I corrected the `Response.Listner<String>` to `<JsonArray>`. And I think I found out, why now it's throwing `String can't be converted to JSONArray` error. Because my JsonObject is like - `_jsonRequest.put("LastUpdatedAt", "2015-03-15 00:30:04");` and this `LastUpdatedAt`, is received by my PHP code through `$_POST["LastUpdatedAt"]`, **which is not working in this case.** That's why my sql query is failing and returning error in string. So any thoughts on How to make it work?

Comment: In continuation to my previous comment, I have also tried using `map` instead of `JsonObject` for my `Post` params, like this - `final Map<String, String> _postContent = new HashMap<String, String>();_postContent.put("LastUpdatedAt", "2015-03-15 00:30:04");` and tried using it at both places - `getBody()` and `getHeaders()`, but still my `$_POST['LastUpdatedAt']` is returning `null`

Comment: You don't need to use `map`. `JsonObject` works well in that case. The problem could be because you send a `JsonObject` including the `LastUpdateAt` to server. So I think you should get the `JsonObject` in PHP instead of `$_post['LastUpdateAt']`

Comment: hanks. I got your point, but I don't know, how to receive JsonObject in PHP? I mean,  I tried to receive it as -  `$_POST['_jsonRequest']` and thought to decode json after receiving, but `$_POST['_jsonRequest']` also returned null.

Comment: You can try this following questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994405/how-do-i-parse-a-json-object-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948191/send-post-request-using-volley-and-receive-in-php

Comment: I have moved to `$_GET`, but I am here to mention, that your 2nd link works. Although, heavy work in volley request is freezing my UI, and I have not found any solution for it, in last 7 days .. I think its time to ask another question

Comment: Perhaps you should use a kinda `progressBar` to figure out that. So you start the progress while the `Volley` fetches data